# how to skip the first line of csv file after using cat in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript. I have a csv file that has a column, I want to read all entries of the column and make it list without column_name.

For example; manual_include.csv file has column name "author" and in that column I have author names such as "tom", "jack", "Sara", "Sonia" etc.

I am using

```
let manualInclude = cat("manual_include.csv");
manualInclude = manualInclude.split("\n");
```

but it reads "author" too in manualInclude. How can I avoid reading column name? I tried using splice as well. But did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
manualInclude = manualInclude.split("\n").splice(0,1);
```

You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=de

Comment: It gives me just "author". I want to read except "author".

Comment: Sounds more like slice()-function - use splice()